# Product details page not showing in magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi I am a newbie in Magento. I have created a new website, store and store view for a new category of products. New site, store, breadcrumb everything is working. But when I click on the link or the image associated with product, page not found message is displaying. Funniest part is if I am doing the same after making a search for the same product, then it will works. Please help:)

Comment: What are the URLs that you are being directed to, both from the listing page, and from the search page.

Comment: http://{base_url}/{new_site}/{category}/{Sub_category}/{product}.html

Comment: Same URL from both locations? That is quite strange that one pulls the proper data, and the other fails.

Comment: http://{base_url}/{new_site}/{category}/{Sub_category}/{product}.html This is the URL in the product listing page, but while searching that sub category and category are not in the URL.

Comment: Have you checked your product Visibility setting. Product Must be set to visible in catalog,Search !!

Answer (score 1):

Please check following settings are done for your product

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still need to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your “var/Cache” & rebuild all indexes from admin > system > index management

Source [Magento blog](http://magento-talks.blogspot.in/2011/07/magento-error-there-are-no-products.html)